# Book about institute in slower time zone

Tags: story-identification

I recall a book I've read some time ago. It is probably from mid-80s, but not sure on that.

> The plot of the story about some sphere or field and time slows down outside, when you goes deeper into that thing.
>
> And humans decided to build an institute inside that thing to increase the technological progress.

Comment: "Time slows down" when you go into the thing? Does that mean that you see somebody go into the thing, and he comes out a week later, and he says it only felt like a minute?

Comment: @user14111 I mean that time slows down outside, when you are inside.

Comment: OK. It was a novel, and it was in English? And do you remember any more of the plot? Were there non-human intelligences involved? Was the "time machine" an invention or a natural phenomenon? Was there some particular project that the humans were working on in that institute? Were they in a war with aliens?

Comment: This kind of reminds me of Charles Sheffield's book [Between the Strokes of Night](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Between_the_Strokes_of_Night).  The doubt I have is that time is slowed for those that enter the deeper layers of sleep that is the premise of the novel, rather than sped up as the OP states

Comment: Does time slow down or does it go backwards? There's Philip K. Dick novel where part of the world is under the "Hobart phase" and everything goes backwards inside of it. The main character works in a government office that has a lot of silly bureaucracy (typical Dick). IIRC, an underground group works to undermine the Hobart phase and restore the whole world to forward time.

Comment: @user14111 I've read it in English, but I have doubts that the author was English-speaking, it may be some famous Russian scifi writer. As I remember it was more "found" rather than "build". Unfortunately, I didn't remember anything else.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Thanks, I'll look into it.

Comment: @Alith Thanks, I'll look into it.

Comment: I vaguely recall reading something about a situation like that in Russian. Do you have any more details about what happened in the story? Also, was it a short story or a novel?

Comment: Any chance this is a blurred memory of Vernor Vinge's "Zones of Thought" idea? I'm pretty sure that at least one story in that setting features a research station in a "faster" zone.